# Histograms plots over multiple Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas data set where I group the data by day.  I would like to take this data and plot histrograms for each day on the same plot but offset to the day in which the data occured. I researched this item and someone stated that you need to use pcolor, which is a nice alternative

Here is a link to some example data..

http://pastebin.com/rKzj5Qzf

I attempted to use the lambda function in the below post,which create a Series.  Pcolor does not like this series and says it need more that 1 value to unpack..

stackoverflow.com/questions/17050202/plot-timeseries-of-histograms-in-python

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
EDIT:
SO the output pasted from the series 'df' in the following
from running the following code snippet:

```
daily = x1.groupby(x1.date).price
f = lambda x: pd.Series(np.histogram(x, bins=bins)[0], index=bins[:-1])
df=daily.apply(f)
```

once, I do this i attempt to pass to  matplotlib

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.pcolor(df.T)
```

This is where I get the problem. I clearly have 3 items :date,price, count
EDIT:::Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-460b943e4ead> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.pcolor(df.T)

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in pcolor(*args, **kwargs)
   2926         ax.hold(hold)
   2927     try:
-> 2928         ret = ax.pcolor(*args, **kwargs)
   2929         draw_if_interactive()
   2930     finally:

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.pyc in pcolor(self, *args, **kwargs)
   7543         shading = kwargs.pop('shading', 'flat')
   7544 
-> 7545         X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolor', *args, allmatch=False)
   7546         Ny, Nx = X.shape
   7547 

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.pyc in _pcolorargs(funcname, *args, **kw)
   7339         if len(args) == 1:
   7340             C = args[0]
-> 7341             numRows, numCols = C.shape
   7342             if allmatch:
   7343                 X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(numCols), np.arange(numRows))

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that you tried to run?

Comment: Can you include the full traceback?

Comment: I edited as requested.